# Crystal Reports XI R2 Compatible with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I'm currently running Crystal Reports XI R2 on SQL 2000. I need to migrate to SQL Server 2008 asap, but am no longer on Crystal Support.

Can anyone tell me if CR XI R2 Server is compatible with SQL Server 2008? I Googled it but came up empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does support sql server 2008.

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/00225757-ab5c-2c10-c1a8-fb9f9f0f4ac2?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true

The sap documentation when moving a sap backend to sql server 2008 has a great document which I have linked you to.

Comment: Thank you, but the document you've linked is for Crystal 2008, not Crystal XI R2. I'm still not sure if XI R2 is compatible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you have found out by now, but it is. You have to upgrade to Service pack 6 of XI and you may also have to install the sql client for 2008. It installs a new ODBC driver for Sql Client 10.